# Creating multiplication table by looping in Java

Tags: java, loops

I was tasked to make a multiplication table from 1-10 but I was not satisfied with my code, it seems to be long:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("1x" + i + " =  " + i + "\t" + "2x" + i + " =  " + (2*i)
                + "\t" + "3x" + i + " =  " + (3*i) + "\t" + "4x" + i + " =  " + (4*i)
                + "\t" + "5x" + i + " =  " + (5*i) + "\t" + "6x" + i + " =  " + (6*i)
                + "\t" + "7x" + i + " =  " + (7*i) + "\t" + "8x" + i + " =  " + (8*i)
                + "\t" + "9x" + i + " =  " + (9*i) + "\t" + "10x" + i + " =  " + (10*i));
    }
```

Output:

```
1x1 = 1   2x1 = 2
1x2 = 2   2x2 = 4
etc.
```

Comment: i would like to maximize the use of looping statements

Comment: What have you tried? What part are you having trouble with? Simply add another loop for the parts of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will format the table how you have it in your example code, and uses two loops:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            System.out.print(i + "x" + j + "=" + (i * j) + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The outer loop controls the rows in the multiplication table and the inner loop controls the columns in the multiplication table. System.out.println() signifies moving into a new row of the table

Comment: this answer is more correct than the highest upvoted one, for the formatting is what the OP wanted

Comment: @sunrize920 Formatting aside, I'd consider the other answer to be a better explanation of the ideas behind the solution.

Comment: I figured the important aspect of the question was not formatting-related

Comment: @BrianAgnew I agree with you, but since he said he was a beginner I wasn't sure if he understood the different between a print() and println() statement

Comment: @BrianAgnew your answer was great don't get me wrong. I was just highlighting to the OP that this would get him the formatting he wanted. PS shut up and play yer guitar!

Comment: Since it is a table, I also consider the formatting but anyway, thanks for your ideas :)

Answer (score 7):

Try something like

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      System.out.println(i + "x" + j + "=" (i*j));
   }
}
```

so you have an inner and an outer loop, controlling what you want multiplied and what you want it multiplied *by*.

To be more explicit you could (should?) rename `i` and `j` as `multiplier` and `multiplicand`

Answer (score 1):

You could use two loops:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(i + "x" + j + "=" + (i*j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    for(int j=1; j<10; j++){
        System.out.println(j+"x"+i+"="+(j*i)+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TableMultiplication {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int table,count,total;
    //Reading user data from console
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //reading  data for table 
    System.out.println("Enter Your Table:");
    table = sc.nextInt();
    //reading input for how much  want to count
    System.out.println("Enter Your Count to Table:");
    count = sc.nextInt();
     //iterate upto the user required to count and multiplay the table and store in the total and finally display
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {

        total = table*i;
        System.out.println(table+"*"+i+"="+total);

    }//for








}//main
}//TableMultiplication
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P11 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a value :");
    int n=s1.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=10;j++)
        {
             System.out.println(i+"x"+j+ "="+(i*j)+"\t");   
        }
    }
}

}
```